# Android/Java Trying to figure out where to put variable declarations

Tags: java, android, variables

I'm new to Android development and so far I have been mostly figuring out how to get tutorial code to work in an app I'm building.  I am struggling in understanding where to declare variables and why I copy and paste some tutorials that end up with errors.

For example, I am trying to learn how to use the ViewFlipper.  From this [tutorial](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-view-flipper-in-android.html) I have issues with Eclipse telling me that vf is not a variable when I use it inside OnClick.  So when I move the line:

```
ViewFlipper vf = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
```

to just above my OnCreate method, then it works.  Why do I see so many tutorials with the variables declared in OnCreate and why doesn't it work for me?  Where is the appropriate place to declare them?  I understand the basics of encapsulation and inheritance, so is OnCreate just like any other method and any variables declared in there are isolated from other methods?  What about my buttons, should I declare those inside my class but outside the OnCreate?

Comment: What is the difference between an *instance/member variable* and a *local variable*? As a general rule, variables should be defined over the minimal required scope.

Answer (score 4):

> **Why do I see so many tutorials with the variables declared in `OnCreate` and why doesn't it work for me?**

Declaring variables within a method, or, outside, really boils down to what kind of [`scope`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) you want to associate with the variable.
Inside a method, you need to be careful that you're declaring a variable before you intend to use it.

> **Where is the appropriate place to declare them?**

*Appropriateness* of where to declare a variable depends entirely on where all you want to use it. Declaring a variable at the class level, when you only intend to use it within a method is unwise. And declaring variables within methods, when a lot many other methods in the class want to access it, and you end up passing the variables to each method - is also unwise. So for now, you can just consider:

1. Declare variables at class - when many methods in the class need to access it.
2. Declare variable in methods - when only the method has use for the variable.

I'd like to add, that **1** and **2** are *not* universal rules that can be applied blindly - but to get off to a start, you can follow them, until you figure out the deeper nuances associated with variable scoping, access specification and lifetime.

I'm not talking about access specifiers here, since, they merit a much detailed understanding, which you can get [here](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/JAVAcourse/ch4/ss2_2.html). And neither have i talked about the difference of instance vs. class variables here, because you'd be better of referring to an official doc like [this one](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

> **I understand the basics of encapsulation and inheritance, so is `onCreate` just like any other method and any variables declared in there are isolated from other methods?**

That's correct.

> **What about my buttons, should I declare those inside my class but outside the `onCreate`?**

UI components in Android are typically required by multiple methods to access. `TextView`, `Button`, etc - usually have states which need to be altered at different times, from different methods - so you'd be better off declaring them at the class level.

Another important reason why you should prefer declaring UI variables at the class level is that you reduce the overhead of having the Android framework create them for every method invocation. As long as your `Activity` instance is alive, the framework holds onto the UI components/variables.

Answer (score 0):

onCreate is just like any other method and all the java rules regarding encapsulation and variable scope apply to it. Declare the ViewFlipper variable as a class member, outside your onCreate method. But instantiate it inside your onCreate method, just as the tutorial says.

Everything in android works just as it does in java. All the programming rules of java are followed here.

Answer (score 0):

this is because outside the onCreate method, variables are global to your class. Aka, any method in your class can access those variables. When you declare variables within onCreate, those variables are only accessible within the brackets of the oncreate method. You should declare your variable outside the onCreate method, and initialize them within the onCreate method:

```
ViewFlipper vf;

onCreate(....)

vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
```

then set your onClickListener

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I think I understand now.  I was tying the declaration and initialization together.  In the tutorial, they don't show the class variables but I'm sure now that the ViewFlipper was declared before the OnCreate.

Comment: Im glad you figured it out! if you feel like this answered your question be sure to accept it as your answer!