# Android app crashes when any math parser is included

Tags: android, crash

I am trying to develop an app which crashes when I include any sort of math parser. App works fine otherwise when I comment out the math parser. I tried other parsers, still the same problem. Any ideas why this is happening? Below are some screen shots.

1. Manifest 
   [image]
2. MainActivity File
   [image]
3. Project Explorer

[image]

LogCat

```
04-24 01:13:15.440: D/AndroidRuntime(3481): Shutting down VM
04-24 01:13:15.440: W/dalvikvm(3481): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a74ba8)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): Process: com.example.calculator, PID: 3481
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calculator/com.example.calculator.MainActivity}: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): }
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):  ^
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481): }
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):  ^
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1785)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.constants.utils.MathParserUtils.transformGropCharsIntoParentheses(MathParserUtils.java:41)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.validators.ExpressionValidator.evalIfExpressionIsWellFormed(ExpressionValidator.java:44)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.validators.ExpressionValidator.validate(ExpressionValidator.java:38)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.LexicalTokenizer.validateExpression(LexicalTokenizer.java:116)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.LexicalTokenizer.assignNewExpression(LexicalTokenizer.java:59)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.LexicalTokenizer.setExpression(LexicalTokenizer.java:47)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.Parser.splitExpressionInTokens(Parser.java:206)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.Parser.shuntingYardAlgorithm(Parser.java:69)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.parser.Parser.setExpression(Parser.java:50)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.google.code.mathparser.impl.MathParserImpl.calculate(MathParserImpl.java:33)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at com.example.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-24 01:13:15.460: E/AndroidRuntime(3481):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post code as text, not images. Likely `MathParserFactory` code is of interest. Also post the exception stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: What is the error? Please post logcat.

Comment: I have added the logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying tonnes of parser, [Expr](https://github.com/darius/expr) seems to work for me. No crashes. Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226863/whats-a-good-library-for-parsing-mathematical-expressions-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

It might help you to post the `Activity.java` instead of the screenshot.

Your app is crashing because `Result` and `MathParser` are being declared outside the scope of where it can be initialized. (''where it can live''). Right now you'd be getting a Null Pointer Exception and so the resultant crash.

Please check [More Info on the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825384/android-java-trying-to-figure-out-where-to-put-variable-declarations).

For now, you can just shift your lines of `MathParser` and `Result` inside `onCreate()` and that should work.

Comment: It doesn't help :(. I have added the logcat. Sorry can't post the mainactivity. Its very long. It will take 2-3 pages.

Comment: Hey...now your problem is the Reg Pattern:    
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1: 04-2  , let you know

Comment: remove the image and pls post your new activity code...only till the onCreate() ends

Answer (score 0):

Use mxparser (http://mathparser.org/)

It generally works well for Java apps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31296109)